# Force Visio to automatically make horizonal, single line connectors

Tags: microsoft-visio, diagrams

In Microsoft Visio 2019, is there some way to automatically cause a connector to be connected to another vertical connector with a straight, horizontal line? The junction between the connectors should therefore automatically move along the vertical connector to keep the horizontal connector straight, without bending or making 90 degree angles. The junction between the lines should be a "Connection Point", such that moving other objects does not cause the junction to "get loose". Preferably, this restriction should remain in place when moving the endpoints/objects afterwards.

A: What I get.

B: What I want to happen automatically (to get this picture I did it manually using Shift+arrows).

[image: A]
A

[image: B]
B

It would be great if it would also be possible to snap to other objects in a similar sort of continuous fashion, keeping connectors straight and restricted to the horizontal or vertical direction, without having to resort to manual precise adjustments (e.g. using Shift+arrows).